# Alternative new line break options

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, impala, array-formulas

I am looking for an alternative to `\n` to create a new line in the results of our queries.

When we run the queries they work just fine the issue comes when we produce Google sheet reports, the letter `n` appears at the end of each line and creates a single long line of information instead of separate rows.

I have looked around but do not see a replacement function to `\n` in impala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **`CHAR(10)`** which acts as line break. then you could wrap it under arrayformula into `SUBSTITUTE` or `REGEXREPLACE` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(YOURQUERYHERE(), "\n$", CHAR(10)))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(YOURQUERYHERE(), "\n", CHAR(10)))
```